# Where is the colour management option?

Tags: uv, color-management

I'm looking for this colour management option:

[image]

However, I can't find it. Where is it? I am currently looking at this:

[image]

I cannot see anywhere how I can go into a "colour management" option like the one shown in the above screenshot.

I'm [fairly new to blender](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/773/is-putting-my-experience-level-a-necessity), so screenshots would be appreciated.

Comment: This one is in Scene tab which is in the Properties window - http://i.imgur.com/kKhvj1g.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find 'Color Management' in the 'Scene' tab of the 'Properties' area (the tall column on the right with the icons at the top).

You are currently on the 'Modifiers' tab (highlighted in orange, which is displaying the 'Displace' modifier), you need to click on the 'Scene' icon (highlighted in red):

[image]

In the 'Scene' tab is where the 'Color Management' options reside.